# Aura: How to get name of instanced component from base component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Given an extensible aura component which is being used as a base component for another component, how can code in the base component get the name of the actual instanced component?  For example:

```
<!-- BaseComponent.cmp -->
<aura:component extensible="true">
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
</aura:component>
```

```
// BaseComponentController.js
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var componentName = component.getType();
        console.log(componentName);
        var parentName = component.getConcreteComponent().getType();
        console.log(componentName);

    }
})
```

```
<!-- InstanceComponent.cmp -->
<aura:component extends="BaseComponentController" >
</aura:component>
```

When an `InstanceComponent` is created and `BaseComponent`'s `init()` runs, both `console.log` lines will output "cBaseComponent".  Is there any way for `BaseComponent`'s `init()` code to learn the name "cBaseComponent", without having to pass it in from the `InstanceComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken - when testing this, I accidentally swapped some code such that I was instancing the base component, which is why I was seeing the same output from both `console.log()` calls.

To answer my own question, the correct way to get the name of the instanced component from a base component is `component.getConcreteComponent().getType()`.